# New Commands with text align

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I would like to create a new command in LaTeX that aligns the text right and left (see example below). Only that I wish the text column were as large as half page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, nohead, nofoot, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\newcommand\sx{\fontfamily{lmss}\Large\flushright}
\newcommand\dx{\fontfamily{lmss}\Large\flushleft}
\begin{document}
\sx Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\bigskip
\dx Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{document}
```

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Your question does not match the [eventual requirement](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8189.png), making the current question-answer pair seem unrelated.

Answer (score 5):

Now that I understand better your problem, thanks to your link, I can propose this, that  seems to fulfill all the requirements.

I define a `\character` command that typesets the characters names uppercase *and* defines the value of `hangindent` for the subsequent  text, which can have several paragraphs.

I also define a `\speci` command. There is only two constraints: new paragraphs, if any,  are to be introduced with the plain TeX command `\endgraf`, and newlines with the `\newline` command, not in the usual way. A `\postspeciskip` length (defaults to 1.5\baselineskip) can be used to set the distance from specifications to dialogs text.

Acts and scenes are considered `\chapter`s and `\section`s. They are conveniently formatted with the help of the `titlesec` package. Some part of the coding would be simpler if the requirement for specifications were smallcaps instead of uppercase.

If you want paragraphs not to be cut at page breaks, you can add this line to the preamble:

```
\interlinepenalty=10000 \parskip0pt plus \baselineskip
```

One can include files and shortcuts for the different characters can be defined in the included files.

Here is an example (with the beginning of Goldoni's La Locandiera).

**Main file:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[noheadfoot, margin=2cm, showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newlength{\postspeciskip}
\postspeciskip = 1.5\baselineskip

\newcommand\character[1]{\par\everypar{\hangindent=0.3\linewidth\hangafter=1}\parskip=0.667\baselineskip plus
2pt\large\makebox[0.3\linewidth][r]{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}:\hskip0.1\linewidth }}

\newcommand\speci[1]{\everypar{\hangindent=0.42\linewidth\hangafter=0}\parskip=0.667\baselineskip plus
2pt\large\raggedright\textit{#1}\vskip\postspeciskip}%

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\centering\bfseries\LARGE}{\MakeTextUppercase\chaptername~\thechapter}{1em}{#1}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}{3\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\newcommand\act[1][]{\chapter{#1}}

\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\Large}{\makebox[0.29\linewidth][l]{\MakeTextUppercase{\chaptername~\thechapter}} \makebox[0.1\linewidth][l]{\MakeUppercase{\sectionname~\thesection}\qquad}} {1em}{#1}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{1\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\newcommand\scene[1][]{\section{#1}}

\AtBeginDocument{\def\chaptername{atto}\def\sectionname{scena}}
\setlength\parindent {0pt}%
\interlinepenalty = 1000\parskip0pt plus \baselineskip
\begin{document}

\sffamily
\include{1stact}

\end{document}
```

**Included file:** (1stact.tex)%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

```
\def\Marchese{\character{Marchese}}
\def\Conte{\character{Conte}}
\def\Fabrizio{\character{Fabrizio}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    \act

\scene
\speci{Sala di locanda.
\endgraf
Il Marchese di Forlipopoli ed il Conte d’Albafiorita}

\Marchese Fra voi e me vi è qualche differenza.
\Conte Sulla locanda tanto vale il vostro denaro, quanto vale il mio.
\Marchese Ma se la locandiera usa a me delle distinzioni, mi si convengono più che a voi.
\Conte Per qual ragione?
\Marchese Io sono il Marchese di Forlipopoli.
\Conte Ed io sono il Conte d’Albafiorita.
\Marchese Sì, Conte! Contea comprata.
    \Conte Io ho comprata la contea, quando voi avete venduto il marchesato.
 \Marchese Oh basta: son chi sono, e mi si deve portar rispetto.
 \Conte Chi ve lo perde il rispetto? Voi siete quello, che con troppa libertà parlando...
 \Marchese Io sono in questa locanda, perché amo la locandiera. Tutti lo sanno, e tutti devono rispettare una giovane che piace a me.
 \Conte Oh, questa è bella! Voi mi vorreste impedire ch’io amassi Mirandolina? Perché credete ch’io sia in Firenze? Perché credete ch’io sia in questa locanda?
 \Marchese Oh bene. Voi non farete niente.
 \Conte Io no, e voi sì?
 \Marchese Io sì, e voi no. Io son chi sono. Mirandolina ha bisogno della mia protezione.
 \Conte Mirandolina ha bisogno di denari, e non di protezione.
 \Marchese Denari? ... non ne mancano.
 \Conte Può essere che lo voglia sposare. Non sarebbe cosa mal fatta. Sono sei mesi che è morto il di lei padre. Sola una giovane alla testa di una locanda si troverà imbrogliata. Per me, se si marita, le ho promesso trecento scudi.

\dotfill

\scene

\speci{Fabrizio e detti.}

\Fabrizio Mi comandi, signore. (Al Marchese.)
\Marchese Signore? Chi ti ha insegnato la creanza?
\Fabrizio La perdoni.
\Conte Ditemi: come sta la padroncina? (A Fabrizio.)
\Fabrizio Sta bene, illustrissimo.

\dotfill
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @ginosap: I understand better now. See my updated answer.

Comment: Very well, but you can put it all in a new command, so that typing **\sx** everything works?

Comment: @ginosap: See my updated answer. Note that the commands and relevant text must be enclosed in braces (that's why an environment would be better).

Comment: Thank you a lot. Your sentence: _Perhaps it would be better to define and use environments rather than commands_   Is it possible to include environments in the commands?

Comment: It is possible for commands with arguments, but here you have switches, their scope is unlimited, unless it's enclosed within braces or an environment. Or you'll have to define another switch that brings you back to the default layout.

Comment: Unfortunately I must ask excuse.
I was too fast and quick and now I'm in confusion.
I send you a picture of what I would do, without additional Latex packages.
Is it possible?
Thank you very much.   http://imgur.com/uewfzav

Comment: @ginospap: The specifications  mentioned in your link are not quite clear to me. Should the scene action specification be ina narrower column than the dialogs column?

Comment: This is the layout that I would get with Latex. Is it possible?
I had thought to define new commands for CHARACTER and comments (in caps)
Thanks for your great patience

Comment: @ginosap: I completely rewrote my solution as I now understand better your requirements. Hope it's closer to what you want.

Comment: Great job!
One last thing: If I want in the future transform the font in **speci** from uppercase to italic? Thanks!

Comment: @ginosap: Just replace `\MakeTextUppercase{#1}` with `\textit{#1}` in the preamble. Of course, all numeric values can be adjusted to your taste/needs.

Comment: Wonderful! Now I need to study your solution. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: You're welcome. It's based on simple plain TeX macros.

Comment: First of all thanks again for your work.
I would have only small things to get to the top:
- How can I adjust the distance between the end of _speci_ and the beginning of a new character?
- I would like to use the command **\include** to get more files attached to the preamble, you can enter commands **\def\Marchese{\character{Marchese}}** within individual files and after \begin? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ginosap: I introduced a `\postspeciskip` length, that defaults to `1.5\baselineskip` and that can be changed through `\postspeciskip=…`. And yes, you can have a main file and included files, with the shortcuts for characters defined in the included files. See my updated answer.

Comment: You are simply the best! Great!

Comment: One last thing: How do I set the height of fonts with pt (like 12pt, 14pt) without using Large/LARGE, etc. In every single part (character, etc). Thanks

Comment: You have  to write `\fontsize{x pt}{y pt}\selectfont`, where x pt, is the  xheight, say  14pt, y pt is the interlineskip (not sure of the exact word, but normally it is `~ 1.2 times xheight`).

Comment: Hi. Is possible to align character name to center? Like this image: http://imgur.com/M9T7SoF

Comment: It's perfectly possible. Please see my modified answer. Is that like you want?

Comment: I ask one thing that perhaps it is impossible.
When I have a sentence too long(like \Conte .....), I would like to remain on the same page and that is not divided into two pages. If it is too long, the entire phrase should go on the next page. Is it possible?

Comment: Another thing: If I want to insert a word within the \begin{center} environment and before I have a \speci, the word is not centered on the page but in the paragraph of \speci. How can you make to center the word?

Comment: @ginosap: there is a solution to prevent paragraph breaking at page breaks. See my updated answer. For the other problem (center environment after a `\speci`, I can't reproduce it. Do you have a minimal example?

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I changed the tex file according to your suggestions and as I studied the commands that you sent me. I attach the master file and the file includes. On the second page you can see the problem by \begin{center}.

Comment: I don't see any file includes?!

Comment: http://1drv.ms/1IKUchp

Comment: http://1drv.ms/1IKUmoS

Comment: Excuse me. I don't still unsterstand how work this forum... Please don't get angry

Comment: I'm not angry… :o). Change your definition of `\centro` to:  
`\newcommand\centro[1]{\hangindent=0pt\fontsize{15pt}{16pt}\selectfont\begin{center}#1\end{center}}`. It works now.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now everything is ok. When you have time could you direct me to a book, a guide, which let me see all the commands you suggested? Thanks again.

Comment: @ginosap: I mainly defined simple plain TeX commands based on `hangindent`. Actually I don't know plain TeX very well. The little I know comes from Victor Eijkhout's very good `TeX by Topic`, which is part  of TeX Live, and that you also can find on CTAN.

Comment: Good Morning. I see that in certain definitions there are ante and post spacings. You can also set in "character"?

Comment: @ginosap: I only see a `\postpreciskip`  that I defined. You would like to have similar definitions for pre- and post-character lengths, that might adjust at will in the preamble?

Comment: Yes, dear Bernard!

Comment: Hi! In my code I'll want to put some text within \speci or within another command. But this text have the same font of \speci or the element before. It's possible to "reset" the font after \speci or another element, so the independent insert text have the "standard" font? Thank you.

Comment: The new discussion link : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271384/build-theatre-script-in-latex