# Change format of character inline

Tags: formatting

Is it possible to change the format of characters in a line of text:

Example:

```
CHARACTER NAME: (include a space)      Dialogue and more dialogue and yet more dialogue 
                                       (The dialogue needs to be a block of text aligned left to the edge of the included space)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Mike

Comment: Is it a `tabular` what you want?

Comment: Are you suggesting I use a table? Would this allow me to use different fonts/format in each cell?

Comment: Would [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204198/new-commands-with-text-align/204201#204201) of mine with the example of a screenplay be helpful to you?

Comment: Of course. What fonts do you want to use?

Comment: You can use a descripton, or better, use a `tcolorbox` and be fancy!

Comment: Bernard: Yes Please! I'm writing to a BBC drama format. Any help you may have would be greatly appreciated. Mike

Comment: Bernard: I'm using LuaLatex. Would this be a problem?

Comment: Karlkoeller: Many thanks. I'll try out your suggestion today. Mike

Comment: What about (possible duplicate): [What are good packages for laying out a play?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3399/5764)