# How to easily quote a theatre dialogue?

Tags: formatting, dialogue

I'm looking for a typesetting to easily quote theatre dialogues. I'm not writing a play, I'm writing a paper on theatre so I need to easily quote dialogues with proper typesetting (characters' names in bold, indentation, etc.). I found packages that create a new document class but I would like to find a package that enables me to use a simple command such as `\speech[stagedirection]{who}{what}`. Any ideas? Or how to create a document class within `\begin{quote}...\end{quote}` ?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: How about the [dialogue package](http://mirror.kku.ac.th/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/frankenstein/dialogue.pdf)?

Comment: Maybe some commands I had proposed in my answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204198/new-commands-with-text-align/204201#204201)  might help?

Comment: @ksgj1 It seems to be exactly what I was looking for, I'll try the dialogue package as soon as possible !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "dialogue" package was exactly what I was looking for. Just make sure to call it before "polyglossia" in the preamble otherwise it will cause errors in the compilation.

```
\usepackage{dialogue}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
```

Very simple to use:

```
\begin{dialogue}
\speak{who1} \direct{how} what
\speak{who2} what
\end{dialogue}
```

Comment: Could you write a answer with some code? It could help much more people... . Please read:[How do I write a good answer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)