# dialog problem with Greek characters

Tags: greek, dialogue

Good morning!

I 'm trying to make a dialog environment using the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{dialogue}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{dialogue}
        \speak{Αυτός} Λόγια, λόγια, πολλά λόγια.
        \speak{Εκείνη} Κι άλλα λόγια, πάρα πολλά λόγια.
    \end{dialogue}
\end{document}
```

But some problems arise:

- Missing ) inserted for expression. \speak{Αυτός}
- Missing = inserted for \ifnum. \speak{Αυτός}
- Missing number, treated as zero. \speak{Αυτός}
- Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ��� (U+)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. \speak{Αυτός}
- Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined(inputenc) in inputencoding `utf8'. \speak{Αυτός}
- Missing ) inserted for expression. \speak{Αυτός}
- Missing = inserted for \ifnum. \speak{Αυτός}
- Missing number, treated as zero. \speak{Αυτός}
- Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ��� (U+)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. \speak{Αυτός}
- Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined(inputenc) in inputencoding `utf8'. \speak{Αυτός}
- Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ��: (U+41C)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. \speak{Αυτός}
- Missing ) inserted for expression. \speak{Εκείνη}
- Missing = inserted for \ifnum. \speak{Εκείνη}
- Missing number, treated as zero. \speak{Εκείνη}
- Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ��� (U+)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. \speak{Εκείνη}
- Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined(inputenc) in inputencoding `utf8'. \speak{Εκείνη}
- Missing ) inserted for expression. \speak{Εκείνη}
- Missing = inserted for \ifnum. \speak{Εκείνη}
- Missing number, treated as zero. \speak{Εκείνη}
- Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ��� (U+)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. \speak{Εκείνη}
- Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined(inputenc) in inputencoding `utf8'. \speak{Εκείνη}
- Missing ) inserted for expression. \speak{Εκείνη}
- Missing = inserted for \ifnum. \speak{Εκείνη}
- Missing number, treated as zero. \speak{Εκείνη}
- Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ��� (U+)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. \speak{Εκείνη}
- Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined(inputenc) in inputencoding `utf8'. \speak{Εκείνη}

I think the problem is with Greek, because when I tried the code below (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386015/how-to-easily-quote-a-theatre-dialogue)), everything (almost) was ok.

```
\begin{dialogue}
\speak{who1} \direct{how} what
\speak{who2} what
\end{dialogue}
```

1. How can I fix the problem?
2. If I can't, is there any alternative solution to make theater-dialog?

Thank's in advanced!

**EDIT**

I use MikTex in window 10 and the log file is [this](https://pastebin.com/0bNLQQD7).

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue on a recent TL installation. Which TeX-distribution do you use? Could you post the log-file (or put it on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com))?

Comment: I use MikTex and the logfile is this: https://pastebin.com/0bNLQQD7

Comment: Could be an encoding problem. Try saving your file explicitly as UTF-8

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to outdated software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the problem was an old version of MiKTeX. Now it works well.